# How do you put an asynchronous callback in beforeEach when using inject?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

In my unit tests, I want to inject certain modules, and I want the `beforeEach` hook to be asynchronous. Basically, I'm looking for something like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, done) {
  ...
}));
```

However, this doesn't work, because Karma complains that there is no provider called `doneProvider`. Basically, it's trying to look up a provider for anything inside inject.

Done typically gets inserted in the `beforeEach` hook like this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  ...
});
```

But how can I inject what I need and still have the `beforeEach` be asynchronous?

I also tried placing an injector function inside the `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
  inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_) {
    ...
    done();
  });
});
```

But the test times out when I do this. For some reason, it seems that `done` cannot be called inside the inject callback. When I place the call to `done` outside the inject function, the stuff I am injecting never gets set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Solution is pretty simple;

```
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$injector_) {
      $injector = _$injector_;
    }));

  beforeEach(function (done) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Got injector: '+$injector);
        done();
      }, 100);
  });
```

SetTimeout is example of async task. You can put there yours. So just do not do any async job inside on inject and it will be fine.

Then you use `$injector.get('$modal')` or whatever you need.